# How to emulate std::is_constant_evaluated in c++17?

Tags: c++, c++17, constexpr

I've got the following code doing what I want in c++20:

```
#include <iostream>

struct IntContainer
{
    int value;
    
    constexpr IntContainer(int init):value(init)
    {
        if(std::is_constant_evaluated())
        {
            value*=2;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout<<"Constructed at runtime"<<std::endl;
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    constexpr int fixed=99;
    int runtime;
    std::cout<<"Enter runtime int value"<<std::endl;
    std::cin>>runtime;
    
    constexpr IntContainer fixed_container(fixed);
    IntContainer runtime_container(runtime);
    return 0;
}
```

For the `fixed` integer value, it constructs my container silently and doubles the value, for the `runtime` integer value, it uses the verbose construction. The implementation allows me to declare `fixed_container` as `constexpr`.

I had to use c++20 for this to use the `std::is_constant_evaluated` feature, but I'm restricted to c++17. Is there some clever template magic I could employ to keep the same behavior without this feature?

Comment: I doubt this would be possible to implement without compiler support

Comment: AFAIK until C++23 `std::is_constant_evaluated` is not something that can be implemented in C++.

Comment: I don't necessarily need to implement `std::is_constant_evaluated`, just keep the stuff in `main` the same. I thought it should be possible to have some sort of template specialization of the constructor or SFINAE my way into it, though it seems maybe it's just not something that can be done.

Comment: You can't overload only based on `constexpr` and the constructor itself has no idea what type of constness the object it is being used to create will have.  What actual problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: You can only achieve what you're after in C++17 if you're willing to move your integer constant from a function parameter into a template parameter.

Comment: That's too bad, it seems I'll just have to wait for my team to jump onto c++20 then. I'm trying to optimize some code based on what's known at compile time, but changing the function parameter to a template parameter would be too disruptive. Thank you for taking a look.

Comment: @jonthalpy, what are you planning to do with the parameter if you are in `constexpr`? AFAIK, you cannot use the parameter like a `constexpr` variable even if `std::is_constant_evaluated`.

Comment: As far as I know, until C++17, `noexcept` operator always returned true for constant expressions. Hence, it could be used to check if a particular invocation of a constexpr function takes the constant expression branch.

Answer (score 2):

Which compiler are you using? While `std::is_constant_evaluated` is only available since C++20, compilers often have extension function like that to determine better algorithms in their library.

For instance, GCC uses `__builtin_constant_p` prior to `is_constant_evaluated`.

Demo: [GCC 6.1 running C++17](https://godbolt.org/z/sjT6dhehe)

Answer (score 0):

I found a way with MSVC compiler compatible from C++11 standard:

```cpp
constexpr bool is_constant_evaluated() noexcept {
    struct C {};
    struct M : C { int a; };
    struct N : C { int a; };

    return &M::a != static_cast<int C::*>(&N::a);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/o8of9z6Gn

---

Explanation:

The member pointer equality operator works differently on compile time and runtime in visual studio. Compile time the equality checks the exact match (`&N::a` and `&M::a` are different, because of a different Base), but runtime it only checks the offset of the class (`&N::a` and `&M::a` are at the same offset: 0). `int M::*` and `int N::*` pointers are not comparable default, but if we create a common base class with the same offset, and use member casts (C++20 ISO: § 7.3.12, 2 and § 7.6.1.7, 12), they will comparable at the common `C` base class.

Comment: This decidedly does not work in GCC and clang.   By the way, why are you citing the C++20 standard?